# Angular Service Calls API in constructor - Jasmine Test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-services

My service is a singleton and in it's constructor it calls a function to make an API call. This works great when the service is initialized as it reduces the complexity and imports required for calling these application start Api's. As well as this makes the service independent as it does not need to rely on let's say the `AppComponent` to import and call the Api functions.

Instantiating the Singleton service on Application Load: `app.module.ts`

```
....

export class AppModule {

  constructor(private applicationSettings: ApplicationSettings) {

  }
}

...
```

### Service: `application-settings.ts`

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApplicationSettings{

  ...

  constructor( private httpClient: HttpClient ){
    this.LoadSettings();
  }

  private LoadSettings() {
    this.httpClient.get<any>(this.settingsApiUrl, { observe: 'response' })
    .pipe(
      retry(3)
    ).subscribe(
      data => this.ApiSuccess(data),
      error => this.ApiError(error)
    );
  }

  ...

}
```

### Unit Test: `application-settings.spec.ts`

```
import { ApplicationSettings } from './application-settings.service';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { environment } from '@environments/environment';

let applicationSettings;
let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
let settingsApiUrl = environment.ApplicationSettings;

describe('ApplicationSettings', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        ApplicationSettings
      ],
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule
      ]
    });
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    applicationSettings = TestBed.get(ApplicationSettings);
    httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);

    // Attempt to catch from constructor
    httpMock.expectOne({
      url: settingsApiUrl,
      method: 'get'
    }).flush({});


    httpMock.verify();
  });

  describe('Tests To Pass', () => {
    fit('should create the app', () => {
      expect(applicationSettings).toBeDefined();
    });

    fit('should be successfull and call ApiSuccess', () => {
      spyOn(applicationSettings, 'ApiSuccess');

      httpMock.expectOne({
        url: settingsApiUrl,
        method: 'get'
      }).flush({});

      applicationSettings.LoadSettings();

      expect(applicationSettings.ApiSuccess).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    ...
  });
});
```

When running my test cases sometimes they will work but 80% of the time they will throw an error. One test may throw 1, another 3 and another may be 5 (not necessarily in that order:

```
[object ErrorEvent] thrown
[object ErrorEvent] thrown
[object ErrorEvent] thrown
```

As well as it will say:

```
Error: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match method: get, URL: //localhost/api/appSettings", found none.
```

If I remove the `httpMock.expectOne` in the main `BeforeEach()` ( Ihave comment on that line indicating trying to catch constructor). Then every test will through this error:

```
Expected no open requests, found 1: GET //localhost/...
```

I am 100% positive it has to do with the Api call in the constructor as to my knowledge every test it creates and uses a new instance of the AppSettings service, which in turn would trigger the LoadSettings API function.

As well as before I moved the call to the constructor all the tests were passing.

Answer (score 1):

After extensive testing I found that the problem was in the way I was taking care of the LoadSettings() APi being called from the constructor. The correct way implemented is:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  applicationSettings = TestBed.get(ApplicationSettings);
  httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);

  // Catches the call from the constructor
  httpMock.expectOne({
    url: settingsApiUrl,
    method: 'get'
  });

  httpMock.verify();
});
```

The main concept was correct before however I removed the `.flush({})` and it works fine. From my reading of flush the definition is follows and can be found [here](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/flush):

> Simulates the asynchronous passage of time for the timers in the
>   fakeAsync zone by draining the macrotask queue until it is empty. The
>   returned value is the milliseconds of time that would have been
>   elapsed.

What I think was happening is the before each happens before each test executes and the `flush()` was somehow taking the `http` requests out of the queue causing fatal issues. During the test. Or with the flush in place it was preventing an api call from occuring.

Comment: This is the working an correct answer. If anyone has a more in-depth explanation of how the flush was causing this issue please update the answer. Thanks.